# Replace author url with different one (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

There are 3 authors in our company blog, **each author has own site url in profile settings**:

```
Mike - http://mike.com
Gelens - http://gelens.com
Admin - http://site.com/company/
```

the links for profiles are:

```
http://site.com/author/Mike/
http://site.com/author/Gelens/
http://site.com/author/Admin/
```

I need to replace a link to Admin's page, so, if there is `<?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>` tag on some page, and the author is Admin, the link must be `http://site.com/company/` instead of `http://site.com/author/Admin/`.

**How can I do that?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like the `the_author_posts_link` function just calls `get_author_posts_url` to get the link, which passes the link through the `author_link` filter before returning it.  In your theme's `functions.php`, you could add something like this (untested):

```
add_filter( 'author_link', 'admin_author_link', 10, 3);
function admin_author_link($link, $author_id, $author_nicename) {
    if( $author_id==1 ) {
        $link = 'http://site.com/company/';
    }
    return $link;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the least heartburn would be [wordpress > the_author_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta).

Have each user add their url in the wordpress user profile, as you have done.  Then in your theme's `functions.php` use `the_author_meta('user_url')`. Remember this will echo the url. To use it as a variable use `get_the_author_meta('user_url')`.

Here is how we did it with the twenty ten theme, this is in `functions.php`

```
function twentyten_posted_on() {
printf( __( '<span class="%1$s">Posted on</span> %2$s <span class="meta-sep">by</span> %3$s', 'twentyten' ),
    'meta-prep meta-prep-author',
    sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark"><span class="entry-date">%3$s</span></a>',
        get_permalink(),
        esc_attr( get_the_time() ),
        get_the_date()
    ),
    sprintf( '<span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="%1$s" title="%2$s">%3$s</a></span>',
        get_the_author_meta('user_url'), //changed from get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ),
        sprintf( esc_attr__( 'About %s', 'twentyten' ), get_the_author() ),
        get_the_author()
    )
);
}
```

Comment: What you modified is around line 568 of functions.php. Here is an alternative that falls back to the author posts if no website is specified:

`esc_url( get_the_author_meta('url') ? get_the_author_meta('url') : get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) )`

There is also a spot in content-single.php around lines 49 and 63

Answer (score 1):

That's URL rewriting with .htaccess, which is possible by editing the .htaccess by hand.

But easier for a beginner with a plugin such as http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/  which seems like it will do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using http rewrites.

Answer (score 0):

I also needed author URL to a different page.

My site is on WordPress and I use oxygen.

I went to my blog page template where I entered the author which is selected dynamically.
there is an option to link the author's name to the archive page or the author's website.

I selected the author's website. Then went to the users on WordPress and went to the authors and added the page I wanted to actually go to as their website.

Comment: The user doesn't seem to use Oxygen and it's not a very good idea to share how to fix his issue particularly with this tool. A general purpose filter would be better in this case.